# Spring could not load JDBC driver class error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I'm getting the below error while executing spring jdbc example in [spring jdbc javapoint](http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-JdbcTemplate-tutorial),

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ds' defined in class path resource [sjdbc1.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are: PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
```

Employee.java I modified as below rest all I took from the javapoint link,

```
1.Employee.java
package com.pro.sjdbc1;

public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float salary;
    // no-arg and parameterized constructors
    // getters and setters
    Employee(int id,String name,float salary){
        id=this.id;
        name=this.name;
        salary=this.salary;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public float getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(float salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.pro</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test1</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Test1 Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xdoclet/xdoclet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xdoclet</groupId>
            <artifactId>xdoclet</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xjavadoc/xjavadoc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xjavadoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xjavadoc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjtools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/aopalliance/aopalliance -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>Test1</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks.

Comment: ```Property 'driverClassName' threw exception``` Can you provide the code, which sets this property?

Comment: where is the spring config file

Comment: Your exception says you are trying to load the oracle jdbc driver, but it is nowhere to be found in your pom.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the Oracle JDBC driver in your classpath. You need to add a dependency in your POM file.

e.g.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
 <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
 <version>x.xx</version>
</dependency>
```

Note this is an example. You will need to add the correct driver version.
You may need to add the appropriate Oracle Maven repository too ([https://maven.oracle.com](https://maven.oracle.com/)) . AFAIK the Oracle JDBC driver is not in the standard Maven central repository.

[See here for how to add the maven Oracle repository](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven_repo.htm#MAVEN9017)

Comment: When I add 
 <dependency>
  <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
  <version>14</version>
 </dependency> 
and after maven build I get Missing artifact ojdbc:ojdbc:jar:14 in pom.xml and in console I got "Failed to execute goal on project Test1: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.pro:Test1:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find ojdbc:ojdbc:jar:14 etc...."

Comment: You will need to add the oracle repository to maven. See updated answer for link to docs.